# Non Existent Clients Connecting To Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Im creating a realtime application using socket.io and its been going alright, until i found somthing strange going on when a client connects to the server. The client will connect, and the `connection` event will properly reflect on the server, but shortly after, a cluster of what i can only describe as "fake clients" start connecting to the server and triggering the `connection` event a seemingly random number of times. These strange connections that come out of nowhere are causing an increasingly big delay on the servers response to actual clients as more start to join. I created an extreamly basic socket.io boilerplate just to see if the strange bug would persist without all the complexity of my application, and to my suprise it did, and i cant understand why. Any info will be greatly appriciated. Here is my basic server and client setup -

```
const http = require("http");                                                                
const fs = require("fs");

const server = http.createServer();                                                                                                                                                       
const io = require("socket.io")(server);                                                                                                                                                  
io.on("connection",() => {                                                                    
console.log("A client has connected!");                                                     
});                                                                                                                                                                                       
server.on("request",(req,res) => {                                                           
fs.readFile("./index.html",(err,data) => {
  if (!err && data) {                                                                         
res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
 res.end(data);                                                                              
} else {
 res.writeHead(500);                                                                          
res.end();
}                                                                                            
});
});                                                                                          
server.listen(3000,() => {                                                                   
console.log("Server is active...");
});
```

note how i am logging that a client connected each time the `connection` event is triggered. Here is the index.html file and client script -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                              
<html>
<head>                                                                                       
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.1/socket.io.min.js" integrity=" sha384- gDaozqUvc4HTgo8iZjwth73C6dDDeOJsAgpxBcMpZYztUfjHXpzrpdrHRdVp8ySO " crossorigin="anonymous"></script>       
<script type="text/javascript">                                                              
const socket = io({autoConnect: false});                                                                                                                                                  
socket.connect();                                                                                                                                                                         
</script>                                                                                    
</head>
<body>                                                                                       
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the console output i get when i connected a single client to the server. Again, its seemingly random each time.

```
A client has connected
A client has connected
A client has connected
A client has connected
A client has connected
```

The first one is genuine, but i have no idea where the rest come from, as they even have a different socket id when i tried to log it out. Any type of feedback is appriciated.

Comment: First off, do your own client connections work just fine?  Have you logged the client IP address to see if these are coming from your client or from some other client?  If you temporarily code your client to immediately send a "hi" message or something like that, then you can easily tell if these connections are coming from your code or from someone else's code.  We need to figure out if this is a problem with your code or if there are some external agents that are probing your server.

Comment: Another idea.  You could set a custom query parameter (using the `query` option when you connect) with your legit client connections and when you get a connection, you can log that query parameter to see if it is there or not.  That will also tell you if it's your code doing the connections or not.

Comment: @jfriend00, I was able to verify for a fact that there aren't any other possible agents that could be connecting to the server. Also, i did find a way to filter out the non genuine clients, however that wasn't enought because all those other "fake" connections are putting dragg on the servers response time, since each client that connects to the server triggers more of these fake connections than the last. This problem is extreamly unique i guess, so ill have to do some more investigating.

Comment: @jfriend00, It may be worth noting that im using multiple chrome tabs as clients, and im aware that it can exibit slightly different behavior than if i were to use separate devices as clients so, that may cause some slight issues but im not completly sure how it could have caused this. I thought that it had to be somthing in my script, since its technicly the script thats triggering all these connections but with how simple this script it, im not on board with that idea anymore.

Comment: So, you've determined that all the connections are from your clients?  You are correct that opening a bunch of connections from the same browser will show some different behaviors because the browser will limit the number of simultaneous http requests (which are involved in the initiation of a socket.io connection) to the same host.  It's possible the issues you see are entirely artificial because of running them all from multiple tabs in the same browser.

Comment: One other thing to check is to make absolutely sure you're running the exact same version of socket.io on client and server as that can cause issues if they are mismatched.  Since you're using a CDN for the socket.io client, it's easy to get versions out of sync when you upgrade your server-side code.

Comment: Here's one thing to change and see if it has any effect.  Your web server is sending back `index.html` for ANY request it receives.  This will include things like when the browser requests `favicon.ico` or when a crawler requests `robots.txt`.  In general, you should not have a web server that doesn't look at the exact `req.url` that was requested because it will be sending back the wrong content when these other standard files are requested.  I'm not sure how that would cause your symptoms, but may as well start fixing things that are wrong.  Send 404, when it's not a specific URL.

Comment: I never gave thought to that before, so ill definitly check to make sure the versions are compatible, since that would definitly result in some unexpected issues.